# Fragment Type Mismatch in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, kotlin, type-mismatch

I'm going along, step by step to try and create a simple tab layout in Kotlin/Android. I've been pretty frustrated by a lot of the tutorials I've found as they either 1) work but are very over engineered making it difficult to see what's happening or 2) Don't seem to work.

This is one of case 2) that is very close to working, but there is something wrong. I've identified the problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_-_Creating_a_Tabbed_Interface_using_the_TabLayout_Component

I have everything exactly as in the tutorial, and the only error that I am getting is in this part:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.tablayoutdemo

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

class TabPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, private var tabCount: Int) : 
            FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {

        when (position) {
            0 -> return Tab1Fragment()
            1 -> return Tab2Fragment()
            2 -> return Tab3Fragment()
            3 -> return Tab4Fragment()
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return tabCount
    }
}
```

I am getting that `Tab1Fragment(), Tab2...` all are not of type `Fragment` which is the return type of `fun getItem`. This is confusing, as they are classes that are declared like so:

`class Tab1Fragment : Fragment()`

That looks like it should be ok to me.

Here's a picture of what I'm seeing in case somebody doesn't believe me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2pjG.jpg

Can someone advise as to what's going on?

Comment: Does your `Tab4Fragment`, etc. extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: do your fragments extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: Check import statement in all Tab fragments. It should be 'import android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two probable errors in your code

Your fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and the `getItem()` method in your adapter returns an `android.app.Fragment` or vice versa.

In any case, ensure that both your fragment and the adapter methods return the same type preferably `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting `Error:(36, 5) 'onCreateView' overrides nothing` in each of my fragments. Blah.

Comment: This might be because you changed the parent class. Remove any method which is overridden and implement them again. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I didn't change any parent class that I can tell, all I did was change the import declaration to the new `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in each of the fragment files. What do you mean by `remove any method that is overwritten`? I understand it's an override class, but I don't know where the function is that its overriding - I don't think I touched it.

Comment: when you changed `android.app.Fragment`  to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` , it effectively changed the parent class. Any method that has a `@Override` annotation over it is an overridden method. So just remove those methods that has `@Override` above it. Android studio will then show you read swiggly lines in the class. Press alt+enter to generate those methods again. Make sure to back up the code inside the methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

**`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`**

Instead of

**`import android.app.Fragment`**

Comment: Now look for androidx.app.fragment vs android.app.fragment as well.
androidx vs android.